# Cannot connect to RealVNC on MacOS over local network (cloud works)

Tags: networking, macos, vnc, realvnc

So I have a Mac mini which I primarily use to run builds on. I have been using its built in vnc server for about a week but it is painfully slow, and for some reason takes a good 2 minutes to initialize a connection. I figured I'd try RealVNC instead.

After initial setup I can connect through RealVNC using the cloud connection, essentially routing my connection over the internet. But both pcs are on the same network so I'd rather use a local connection. Thing is this doesn't seem to work -at all-. No matter what I tried I keep getting connection refused.

Things I've tried:

- Adding it to Accessibility apps
- Changing the port to 5800 and 5901
- Connecting to the same computer with SSH to see if that works (it does)
- Turning on debug logging (nothing in there)
- Ensuring my firewall is off (it is)

Both computers are connected to the same switch, but if that were the problem then SSH wouldn't work either.

Anyone have any idea why this isnt working?

Comment: just to clarify, you are attempting to target a LAN IP like 10.x.y.z, 172.16.x.y, or 192.168.x.y, right? are you connecting by name or IP?

Comment: That's correct. I am connecting by IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connecting via RealVNC cloud does not necessarily mean that the traffic is routed via the internet - If the machines are on the same network it should automatically figure this out and route the data locally. If you go to connection information in the viewer you can tell if it's falling back to relaying via cloud servers because it will say something like "connected via..."

Connecting directly over tcp is only available if you have subscribed to an enterprise plan, but you shouldn't need to do this as it should just work as described above.

Comment: Awesome! It does appear that it is connecting locally, despite using the cloud to initiate it. Would've been nice if it said somewhere that straight tcp connections aren't supported. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it may only be listening on localhost and tunneling the connection to the Internet so that the application is not actually listening on its external/forward-facing LAN interface.

SSH to the computers and do `sudo lsof -iTCP:5901` to see if they are listening on all ports or just localhost, and see if there are any obscure settings or hidden config files or directories in your `$HOME` directory or somewhere else that the application accesses.  If so, change `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` to either your LAN IP address or `0.0.0.0`.

This will also show if the IPs are listening on IPv6 instead of IPv4, which would also cause this behavior of not being able to connect to their respective IPv4 addresses over the local network.

Comment: `lsof` does show ipv6 addresses (as well as ipv4) but the host is a wildcard. I also verified in the vnc config that it is listening on all available IPs. Does the fact that it listens on ipv6 itself pose an issue?

Comment: I meant that `lsof -iTCP` would show IPv6 as well as IPv4, as opposed to `lsof -i4TCP`, which only shows IPv4.  Sorry if I wasn't more clear.  If the host is a wildcard, that means it's listening on all interfaces.